# awk is not picking string and pipe as delimiter

Tags: linux, awk, pipe

I have a file where each record has a word `"TST_BI|"`  and I need to use as a delimiter and populate the value after this string to a file . There is only one occurrence of this string in each record.

It is working fine in AIX environment with below command.
`awk -F "TST_BI|" '{print $2}' file.txt`.

But when I migrated the code to Linux and tried the same, command is **NOT** working, where the value  `"|"` is also getting populated. Below are the output from both AIX and Linux

**Input :**

```
<14>1 2017-08-31T04:13:47.2345839+00:00 loggregator ecsdasc0985-cs656-4asdsds-asds-asdasg6ds73 [DEV/2] - - TST_BI|DATE~2017-08-31 04:13:47,095|TIMESTAMP~04:13:47|TEST_ID~biTestExecutor-2|COUNTRY_CODE~XX|GROUP_TESTS~BZAG
```

**OutPut from AIX :**

```
DATE~2017-08-31 04:13:47,095|TIMESTAMP~04:13:47|TEST_ID~biTestExecutor-2|COUNTRY_CODE~XX|GROUP_TESTS~BZAG
```

With same command, 
**Linux Output** is

```
|DATE~2017-08-31 04:13:47,095|TIMESTAMP~04:13:47|TEST_ID~biTestExecutor-2|COUNTRY_CODE~XX|GROUP_TESTS~BZAG
```

A pipe is getting populated and which is not treating as delimiter.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 3):

vertical bar char `|` specified with adjacent characters is treated as regex alternation operator/alternation group. In such case, to treat `|` literally - it should be escaped `\\|` or put into a character class `[|]`:

```
awk -F'TST_BI[|]' '{print $2}' file.txt
```

The output:

```
DATE~2017-08-31 04:13:47,095|TIMESTAMP~04:13:47|TEST_ID~biTestExecutor-2|COUNTRY_CODE~XX|GROUP_TESTS~BZAG
```